# C# Dictionary always returns last value

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, dictionary, field

I have created dictionary and inserted 3 fields to it:

```
Dictionary<string, Map> targets = new Dictionary<string, Map>();
targets.Add("Pláž - střed", new Map("Pláž - sever", "Vrak letadla", "Džungle", "Vrak letadla"));
targets.Add("Vrak letadla", new Map("Pláž střed", "nothing", "Roští", "nothing"));
targets.Add("Roští", new Map("nothing", "nothing", "Tenký lesík", "Vrak letadla"));
```

When I tried to get field `targets[Pláž - sever]`, map constructor parameters contained `"nothing", "nothing", "Tenký lesík", "Vrak letadla"` - value of the last field, value is the same for 2nd and 3rd field. Can you please help me solve that problem?
I need 1st field to return its value, and not the value of the third field.

Comment: Please add the code how you query the dictionary.

Comment: `targets["Pláž - sever"]` should throw a `KeyNotFoundException` as you never added an item with that key. Please show your real code or elaborate a bit more to make your question clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is a little odd to start with - but I *suspect* you'll find that your `Map` class has *static* fields instead of instance fields. That would mean you've got one set of fields related to the type, and not to any particular *instance* of the type... so every time you overwrite the fields, you're losing all your previous data.

Just a guess though...

Comment: Yes! you were right, fields in Map class were static, I didnt even try to look to Map class, I though problem is In the main class, thank you, I will accept this one

Comment: That was a pretty good guess - sure it comes from the experience!

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is:

```
var a1 = new Map("Pláž - sever", "Vrak letadla", "Džungle", "Vrak letadla"));
var a2 = new Map("Pláž střed", "nothing", "Roští", "nothing"));
```

run this code in debugger and inspect values of a1 and a2. Chances are something is messed up with your Map class, such as fields declared static or something else of that nature

Answer (score 0):

You have not added any item in the dictionary with the `Key` `"Pláž - střed"`so you can't get that item coz it's simply not available.

So try to add an item with `"Pláž - střed"` key and then access it.